# Maximum value between two lists, and their indexes

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have a nested dictionary with list of values, I want to have 
- the maximum index wise value between two lists
- the 'id' for each max value (by id I mean from which list is the value coming and what index it is).

I already have the index wise max value between the two lists, what I need with is the 'id'.

```py
#create dictionary:

test = {}
test['A'] = {}
test['A']['number'] = [2,2,3]
test['A']['id'] = ['x','y','z']
test['B'] = {}
test['B']['number'] = [1,3,2]
test['B']['id'] = ['a','b','c']

#this the maximum index-wise value between the two lists
max_list = [max(*l) for l in zip(test['A']['number'], test['B']['number'])]

print(max_list)
```

What I would like is another list with the following:
['x','b','z']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make an inner zip of `id` and `number` so we know which id belongs to which number,

then use max with a custom key function (by number), then split them:

```py
test = {}
test['A'] = {}
test['A']['number'] = [2,2,3]
test['A']['id'] = ['x','y','z']
test['B'] = {}
test['B']['number'] = [1,3,2]
test['B']['id'] = ['a','b','c']

tuple_list = [max(*l, key=lambda t: t[1]) for l in zip(zip(test['A']['id'],test['A']['number']), zip(test['B']['id'],test['B']['number']))]
max_num_list = [t[1] for t in tuple_list]
max_id_list = [t[0] for t in tuple_list]

print(max_num_list)
print(max_id_list)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 3]
['x', 'b', 'z']
```

Comment: if having the result lists as tuples is ok, you can even split them using `zip` in one line: `max_id_list, max_num_list = [*zip(*tuple_list)]`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!